# How to stop parenting distorting mesh?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting, parent

I followed a tutorial to create this armature for my mesh. [image]

but every time I try to parent them together, it distorts the mesh completely.

[image]

I have tried to ctrl+p with automatic weights, recalculating norms and I have tried manually painting weight but all don’t seem to help.

This is what happens when I go into pose mode and try to move arms and legs.

[image]

[image]

I’m still pretty new to Blender so would need any kind responder to assume I know nothing!

I have tried to upload the file but it says that the file is too large and I don't see what I can remove to make it smaller.

Comment: If your file with just a single character in it is over 30 Meg (the limit for blend-exchange) it's probably too dense for parenting to work. There are other sharing sites like WeTransfer, Google Drive or Dropbox that folks here use.  If you right-click on the bottom status bar in Blender you can add the Scene Statistics and memory used to the Blender version so that you can see how many verts, faces and tris there are. In Edit mode, you can try Decimate Geometry under the Mesh > Clean Up menu and Merge by Distance under that submenu will delete duplicate geometry.

Comment: Thanks @JohnEason I think I got carried away adding details and clothes before adding my armature. I have joined everything together so perhaps I need to start over and sort the armature out before adding more details.